# getOAuthToken API replacement for Service Integrations?

Tags: docusignapi

We're using the DocuSign embedded signing capabilities via a [service integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/glossary.html#serviceintegration), and are using the [getOAuthToken](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/getOAuthToken/) API call. We noticed from the documentation that it says that this API is deprecated; what does that mean? Is this call going to be removed in the future, and if so, is there a replacement that we can use?

We're trying to avoid storing the password for our account in our application, we'd rather store the tokens with the possibility of revoking them as necessary, so the [Legacy Header Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) option doesn't fulfill our needs. Because we're doing a service integration, not interactive authentication, the [Authentication Service](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html) and the [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html) options don't fulfill our needs either.

Does anybody have any knowledge of how the deprecation process works, or any suggestions?